# php isset($_post) is not working?

Tags: php, forms

I am working with this issue since last few hours and also searched the related questions on stack overflow. I have a simple html form

```
<form name="user_verification" action="action.php" method="POST">
 Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and here is the php script in action.php file

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
echo 'yes';
}else{
echo 'no';
}
```

It always display "no". I tested my php script using this

```
 if(1==1) 
    {
    echo 'yes';
    }else{
    echo 'no';
    }
```

In this case, it displays "yes". This means that problem is with isset($_POST['submit']) function but I can't find out the solution. please help in this regard. thanks

Comment: it will echo `yes` once the form is submitted

Comment: You should first of all check `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: var_dump($_POST) give empty array(0) { }

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)`, `var_dump($_SERVER)`, `var_dump` everything else that may be relevant, look at your browser's network inspector to see if the request is being made as expected.

Comment: try it self, it works! if you click submit button, php says 'yes'!

Comment: Its better to check if the $_POST variable isset or not first. then check other values.

Comment: @rohit the `$_POST` var is always set - even in CLI mode weirdly.

Comment: better once check what's coming into `$_POST` using `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: The reason it displays "no" is because you most likely have both your HTML form and PHP inside the same page. Once you click submit, it will show "yes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For robustness its best to check the method against the request.
This is a simple example of a form processor validating a post request.

```
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    if (!isset($_POST['required_data'])) {
        http_send_status(400);
        exit;
    }

    echo 'OK';
}
```

You will still need to check with `isset` against the fields you require.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe somewhere $_POST values are emptied/unseted. This may be due to php configuration or as security measure (i.e. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading). You may check $_REQUEST and also check if you can get $_GET values (method of form is get).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, it's working for me. See this [for more info](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/examples/formfinale.php).

In index.php

```
<form name="user_verification" action="action.php" method="POST">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

in action.php

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
 {
 echo 'yes';
 }else{
  echo 'no';
 } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code will only display the submitted values if the submit button was clicked.

isset( ). This is an inbuilt function that checks if a variable has been set or not. In between the round brackets, you type what you want isset( ) to check. For us, this is $_POST['Submit']. If the user just refreshed the page, then no value will be set for the Submit button. If the user did click the Submit button, then PHP will automatically return a value

```
$var = '';

// This will evaluate to TRUE so the text will be printed.
if (isset($var)) {
    echo "This var is set so I will print.";
}
```

You may also use the    `var_dump(isset());`      // TRUE 
to output the return value of `isset().`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

It works only when you submit the form.

So, unless you submit the form, it will always print `no`.

Comment: ha, surely nobody's that daft ;)